# Snowpipe auto-ingest from Azure Blob storage

Tags: azure, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to set up auto ingest for Snowpipe however can't get it working although I am properly following Snowflake documentation.

The pipe works when REFRESH is used, which makes me think there is no problem with the COPY INTO statement.

External stage is working fine and I can list files using the same path as specified in the pipe.

When I click on the Consent URL for notification integration it takes me straight to Snowflake website (does that mean it has permissions?). I don't have permissions to see Azure AD app in Azure Portal.

The Azure App for notification integration has 'Storage Queue Data Contributor' role assigned.
When I run SYSTEM$PIPE_STATUS it shows these values:

```
executionState:RUNNING
pendingFileCount:0
notificationChannelName:--correct value--
numOutstandingMessagesOnChannel:1 (this keeps increasing when more blobs are added)
lastReceivedMessageTimestamp: correct timestamp for latest blob creation time
lastPulledFromChannelTimestamp: current timestamp
```

There is no error message though.

Copy history for the target table also confirms that there is no data being loaded.

What could be causing this issue?